# Docker + nuxt.js установка

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

Создал файл Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.5.0
ENV APP_ROOT /

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

и файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "lsf",
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": "3000"
    }
   },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt"
  }
}
```

выполняю команду

```
docker build -t extrememod/lsf .
```

выдает ошибки

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.24kB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:14.5.0
 ---> 37ad18cd8bd1
Step 2/8 : ENV APP_ROOT /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24eafde3e37f
Step 3/8 : ENV NODE_ENV production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7fcbe82b387a
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c74f25b1e544
Step 5/8 : ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
 ---> 82eee2797f8d
Step 6/8 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in 1b63010d1b38
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-13T21_26_05_159Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm ci' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, ошибка:

```
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.
```

Следовательно, нужно создать `package-lock.json`

```
npm install --package-lock
```

То-есть, `dockerfile` должен выглядеть вот так:

```
FROM node:14.5.0
ENV APP_ROOT /

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install --package-lock
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```